# Creating a dataframe with the sum of an amount column from timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    CCY Pair        Time    Amt   
0     EURUSD    13/05/2023  1000    
1     EURUSD    13/05/2023  2000    
2     EURUSD    14/05/2023  3000   
3     EURUSD    14/05/2023  5000    
4     GBPEUR    15/05/2023  4000
```

I'd like to sum the time column so the dataframe looks like this:

```
    CCY Pair        Time    Amt   AmtSum
0     EURUSD    13/05/2023  1000  3000   
1     EURUSD    14/05/2023  3000  8000    
2     GBPEUR    15/05/2023  4000  4000
```

My code doesn't seem to sum the amounts correctly:

```
df2= pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

StartDate = df['Time']
EndDate= StartDate.iloc[::-1]

dfx=df
dfx['StartDate'] = StartDate
dfx['EndDate'] = EndDate

dfx['AmtSum'] = dfx.apply(lambda x: df.loc[(df.Time >= x.StartDate) & 
                                            (df.Time <= x.EndDate), 'Amt'].sum(), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

YOu can try `.groupby()` + `.agg()`:

```py
x = df.groupby('Time').agg({'CCY Pair':'first', 'Amt': ['first', 'sum']})
x = x.droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index()
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
         Time CCY Pair   Amt   Amt
0  13/05/2023   EURUSD  1000  3000
1  14/05/2023   EURUSD  3000  8000
2  15/05/2023   GBPEUR  4000  4000
```

---

Or if you want to group by `Time`/`CCY Pair`:

```py
x = df.groupby(['Time', 'CCY Pair']).agg({'Amt': ['first', 'sum']})
x = x.droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index()
print(x)
```

Comment: This is great, but how do I then display this as say a bar chart?

I'm trying to use matplotlib: 
plt.plot(x["Time"], x["Amt"])
plt.show()